# Multiple CSS style types in HTML

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to create a Paragraph tag that uses Times New Roman Font and use margin to change the text location (make it higher on the website). Here is some sample code:

```
<div id = "WhoAreWe2">
      <p style=font-family:Times New Roman;"margin-top: 100px">who are we? </p>
</div>
```

It's just something that's been bothering me, using semicolon means you're using multiple CSS types right?

Comment: What do you have against using a separate CSS file?

Comment: Is that your actual markup, because you have errors in it.  It should be: style="font-family:Times New Roman; margin-top: 100px"

Comment: The question has been answered correctly by others.  Remember also that http://validator.w3.org/ is your friend.

Comment: As a matter of fact everybody answered it wrong, so adding a fix to an error everybody made and a comment: `style="font-family:'Times New Roman', serif; margin-top: 100px"`. You need to include fonts names with spaces within single or double quotes, and you need to add a default family, in this case serif

Comment: What do you mean by "CSS style types"? Do you mean properties? Read a basic tutorial. For instance, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors tells you right at the beginning that "The semicolon after the property-value pair separates it from other property-value pairs in the same declaration."

Comment: Thanks @torazaburo , Just a little mistake.

Comment: @Fabio Thanks but I just decided to use a CSS file (:

Comment: "Font family names containing whitespace should be quoted", so `font-family: 'Times New Roman'` See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family.

Comment: @Fabio: Please put that in an answer so I can upvote it (since I was wrong, too) and OP can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes using semi-colon you can declare multiple styles . The way you have declared styles is called `inline styles`.

There are 3 types

**Inline styles**- are defined within the html markup of a particular element.

```
<div id = "WhoAreWe2"> <p style="font-family:Times New Roman; margin-top: -100px;">who are we? </p></div>
```

**Embedded styles**-  are defined in the `<head>` section of the "current" web page.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>embedded styles</title>
<style type="text/css">
.who-para{
font-family:Times New Roman;
 margin-top: -100px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id = "WhoAreWe2"> <p class="who-para">who are we? </p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**External styles** -  are defined on the External Style Sheet, which is linked to the web page.

Refer this link : **[Cascading stylesheets](http://www.expression-web-tutorial.com/Types_CSS_Styles.html#.VAFVHPldWSo)**

Answer (score 0):

You're close.

Correct syntax is like this...

```
<div id = "WhoAreWe2"> <p style="font-family:Times New Roman; margin-top: 100px">who are we? </p></div>
```

All of the styles for a particular element go within the quotes. .

You can also have external stylesheets; which is very common because it is easier to manage.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p style="font-family:Times New Roman;margin-top: 100px">
```

Fix your opening and closing double quotes.
BTW, You should practice separating your markup and styling using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, but you may run into syntax issues the way you have it, change it so that the whole attribute value is in quotes, and if you want it higher, then change 100px to be negative.

```
<div id = "WhoAreWe2"> <p style="font-family:Times New Roman; margin-top: -100px;">who are we? </p></div>
```